# Drop table that contains only numbers in name - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have problem for dropping database table when table name contains only numbers. So, my implementation works correctly for cases where database table contains letter+numbers.

This is my implementation:

```
$this->dbforge->drop_table($table_name);
```

I've tried to use back-tick(`) and my query looks like:

```
DROP TABLE `234`
```

Also i tried using single quote(') and this also didn't work.

I know that its bad practice to use names for tables and columns that contains only numbers as their name, but i want to know why i can dynamically create this type of table, but cant drop them.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: that's because its not a valid table name

Comment: But why it letting me to create this kind of table?

Comment: haha, im looking for actual explanation of this kind of issue :) (+ for second answer :P)

Comment: This tables are created from codeigniter application, not using eternal query.

Comment: Can you show your how is this being implemented?

Comment: I've updated the question with my implementation.

Comment: Yes, I've tried both versions (using ' and `) and both didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and works just fine. Let me know if it is something you have tried.

[image: 234]

Also tested this and also works. What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is okey! Thanks.